# Background image not showing entirely in tablet

Tags: html, css, image, ipad, tablet

My background image is showing only inside the content blocks (screenshot), FYI I have a little animation (fadeIn) for the content but nothing special besides that.

here's my css :

```
.template_home { 
background: url("../Images/bg_home.jpg") no-repeat top center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%; 
color: #292a2c;
position: relative; 
overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this pls?!

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: write a media query for tablet and apply background-size:cover;

Comment: as per the screenshot, you need to set `outer-wrapper` that contain `100%` of `width` and set `background-image` to it. hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
height: 100%
margin: 0 auto;
background-position: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove

```
overflow: hidden;
```

see this tutorials gonna help you

> https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/